# How to specify GStreamer path for Qt-GStreamer build

Tags: qt, ubuntu, embedded, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

I have gstreamer installed on my target system in /opt/gstreamer. When I try to build Qt-Gstreamer on my development host using cross-compiling tool I get:

```
* GStreamer (0.10.33 or higher)  <http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/>
     Required to build QtGStreamer
```

How can I specify Gstreamer path for building Qt-GStreamer? I use NFS for my target filesystem so it's on my dev host.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pkg-config:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<pathToGStreamerRoot>/lib/pkgconfig
```

pkg-config supplies the required compilation options so if you use `make` then it would automatically use the GStreamer at the specified path.

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

Is going to list all libraries managed by pkg-config.